# tengo algunos problemas con Angular y Angular Material, no toma los estilos

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material, framework

Estoy aprendiendo a usar Angular con Angular Material, pero tengo un problema, hize una Toolbar en un componente nuevo, éste funciona, pero en otro componente no los toma, hay botones sin estílo de Material, por alguna razón.

en **material.module.ts**
tengo lo siguiente

```
    import { MatToolbarModule } from '@angular/material/toolbar';
    import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
    import { MatCardModule } from '@angular/material/card';
    import { MatButtonModule } from '@angular/material/button';
    import { MatIconModule } from '@angular/material/icon';
    @NgModule({
    imports:  [MatToolbarModule , MatCardModule , MatButtonModule , MatIconModule ],
    exports: [MatToolbarModule , MatCardModule , MatButtonModule , MatIconModule ]
    
    })
    
    export class MaterialModule {}
```

en mi **app.module.ts**
lo siguiente

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { HeaderComponent } from './shared/components/header/header.component';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { MaterialModule} from './material.module';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    HeaderComponent,
  ],
  exports: [MaterialModule],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    FormsModule,
    MaterialModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    HttpClientModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

y en el **products.component.html**
lo siguiente

```
    <section class= 'products'>
        <mat-card class='card' *ngFor= 'let product of products'>
            <mat-card-header> {{product.name}} </mat-card-header>
            <mat-card-content> {{product.description}} </mat-card-content>
            <mat-card-actions> 
                <button mat-flat-button color="primary">Buy</button>
            </mat-card-actions>
        </mat-card>
    </section>
```

Answer (score 0):

> De esta forma acepta a Angular material tanto desde un componente tool
> que se encuentra declarado en el modulo app.module como de otro header
> de caracteristica Lazy-loading en el modulo que contiene a este ultimo
> es necesario importar a MaterialModule en el caso del componente tool
> es por supuesto necesario declararlo en app.module
> agregar material con ng add @angular/material
> generar modulo material con ng g m material -m  app.module
> al crear un nuevo componente siempre ver que  esta declarado en un modulo
> si cargamos un componente en forma Lazy loading si se requiere importar MaterialModule         a su modulo

```js
// material.module.ts


    import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
    import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
    import { MatToolbarModule } from '@angular/material/toolbar';
    import { MatCardModule } from '@angular/material/card';
    import { MatButtonModule } from '@angular/material/button';
    import { MatIconModule } from '@angular/material/icon';


    @NgModule({
      declarations: [],
      imports: [
        CommonModule,
        MatToolbarModule , MatCardModule , MatButtonModule,
        MatIconModule
      ],
      exports: [MatToolbarModule , MatCardModule , MatButtonModule,
     MatIconModule ]
    })
    export class MaterialModule { }




//app.module.ts


    import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
    import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';

    import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
    import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
    import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
    import { ProductsComponent } from './products/products/products.component';

    import { MaterialModule } from './material/material.module';
    import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
    import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
    import { ToolComponent } from './tool/tool.component';


    @NgModule({
      declarations: [
        AppComponent,
        ProductsComponent,
        ToolComponent 
        
      ],
      imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        AppRoutingModule,
        BrowserAnimationsModule,
        FormsModule,
        HttpClientModule,
        MaterialModule,

      ],
      providers: [],
      bootstrap: [AppComponent]
    })
    export class AppModule { }









//app.component.html
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>


//-routing.module.ts



    import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
    import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';

    import { ProductsComponent } from './products/products/products.component';

    const routes: Routes = [
    {path: '',
      component: ProductsComponent
    },


      { path: 'header', loadChildren: () => import('./header/header.module').then(m => m.HeaderModule) }

    ];

    @NgModule({
      imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
      exports: [RouterModule]
    })
    export class AppRoutingModule { }



// products.component.html



    <app-tool></app-tool>
    <p>products works!</p>
    <section class= 'products'>
      <mat-card class='card' *ngFor= 'let product of products'>
          <mat-card-header> {{product.description}} </mat-card-header>
          <mat-card-content> {{product.manteca}} </mat-card-content>
          <mat-card-actions>
              <button mat-flat-button color="primary">Buy</button>
          </mat-card-actions>
      </mat-card>
    </section>
<a routerLink="header"> Go modulo Header a toolbar </a>

// header.module.ts


    import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
    import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';

    import { HeaderRoutingModule } from './header-routing.module';
    import { HeaderComponent } from './header.component';
    import { MaterialModule } from '../material/material.module';


    @NgModule({
      declarations: [
        HeaderComponent
      ],
      imports: [
        CommonModule,
        MaterialModule,
        HeaderRoutingModule
      ]
    })
    export class HeaderModule { }




// header.component.ts





    <p>header works!</p>
    <mat-toolbar>
      <button mat-icon-button class="example-icon" aria-label="Example icon-button with menu icon">
        <mat-icon>menu</mat-icon>
      </button>
      <span>My App</span>
      <span class="example-spacer"></span>
      <button mat-icon-button class="example-icon favorite-icon" aria-label="Example icon-button with heart icon">
        <mat-icon>favorite</mat-icon>
      </button>
      <button mat-icon-button class="example-icon" aria-label="Example icon-button with share icon">
        <mat-icon>share</mat-icon>
      </button>
    </mat-toolbar>



// header-routing.module.ts





    import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
    import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
    import { HeaderComponent } from './header.component';

    const routes: Routes = [{ path: '', component: HeaderComponent }];

    @NgModule({
      imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
      exports: [RouterModule]
    })
     export class HeaderRoutingModule { }
```

Answer (score 0):

Debes agregar dentro de tu hoja de estilos globales "style.css" la variable del tema que elegiste.

```
@import "~@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css";
```

Comment: El uso de @import está desaconsejado, es mejor usar `@use`: https://sass-lang.com/documentation/at-rules/import